How to make a luminance mask in Flutter? like mask-type: luminance in CSS
I am able to use BlendMode.srcATop to make an image clip another, however, how can I make only the brightest part to be revealed?
Luminance in CSS masks: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-type#examples
Example. Make the below mask

into this

